# XHR request in for loop fires only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, onclick

Im making a website for this spa bussiness. It has four horizontal sections with several buttons each, every button should display its own "treatment information" in the div "#container_xhr_info".

To avoid stuffing the HTML I put all the treatment divs in their own html file in a folder, so when making click on a button the XHR request should fetch the button's file and display it inside the container.

Ive added a Click Event to the buttons with a for loop, the event fires the xhr. I also saved the file URLs in an array to put them inside the open() also with a for loop. So far the code works but it displays the 4th URL in the array on every button (the "peeling" one). I havent found a solution to this specific case.

```js
let array_asyncs_facial_location = ["Asyncs/facial/radio.html",
                                    'Asyncs/facial/diamante.html',
                                    'Asyncs/facial/limpieza.html',
                                    'Asyncs/facial/peeling.html',
                                    'Asyncs/facial/acne.html',
                                    'Asyncs/facial/rosacea.html',
                                    'Asyncs/facial/pustulas.html'];

let tratamientos_facial = document.getElementsByClassName('tratamientos_facial');

for(var i = 0; i < tratamientos_facial.length; i++){

    tratamientos_facial[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

        let url = array_asyncs_facial_location[i];
        xhr.open('GET', url );
        
        xhr.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
            if (xhr.status == 200){
                let plantilla = xhr.response;
                let container_xhr_info = document.querySelector('#container_xhr_info');
                container_xhr_info.innerHTML = plantilla;
            }
        })

        xhr.send();
    })
}
```

Comment: You overwrite the `innerHTML` for each request. Try `container_xhr_info.innerHTML += plantilla;` so you add to it instead

Comment: I'd look into PHP instead. It was basically invented to compose a big HTML document from smaller parts. This will also increase the SEO, since search engines usually don't run JS code when crawling a website.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` that you're relying on to get your URL isn't resolved until the click function fires, at which point it's not the same value as when you set up the listener. There's a better way. Pass through the `event` argument in your listener and set the url dynamically using `element.setAttribute()`, then get the value in `element.dataset`. Setting an attribute like `data-url` allows us to get it simply with `element.dataset.url`

```js
let array_asyncs_facial_location = ["Asyncs/facial/radio.html",
  'Asyncs/facial/diamante.html',
  'Asyncs/facial/limpieza.html',
  'Asyncs/facial/peeling.html',
  'Asyncs/facial/acne.html',
  'Asyncs/facial/rosacea.html',
  'Asyncs/facial/pustulas.html'
];

let tratamientos_facial = document.getElementsByClassName('tratamientos_facial');

for (var i = 0; i < tratamientos_facial.length; i++) {
  // set the URL as an attribute of the element itself so we can get it later
  tratamientos_facial[i].setAttribute('data-url', array_asyncs_facial_location[i]);
  tratamientos_facial[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // make sure to pass the event argument through
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    // now we just query the dataset property 
    let url = event.target.dataset('url');
    xhr.open('GET', url);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        let plantilla = xhr.response;
        let container_xhr_info = document.querySelector('#container_xhr_info');
        container_xhr_info.innerHTML = plantilla;
      }
    })

    xhr.send();
  })
}
```